# How to make cin accept a single digit only c++

Tags: c++, validation, cin

So we were challenged by a teacher to make this simple game into a c++ program.

English is not my primary language but I'll try to explain. I'm a beginner so these will not be efficient, but I'm still proud of what I did so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int secret[3], i = 0, x, y, z, a, b, c, guess = 1, tries = 9;
    bool correct = false;

    srand(time(0));

    do
    {
        secret[i] = rand() % 10;
        i++;
    } while (i <= 2);

    x = secret[0];
    y = secret[1];
    z = secret[2];

    //cout << x << y << z << endl; <--- for debugging purposes

    cout << "=================================================\n\n";
    cout << "       I HAVE THREE SINGLE DIGIT NUMBERS\n\n";
    cout << "  YOU HAVE TEN TRIES TO GUESS ALL THREE DIGITS\n\n";
    cout << "=================================================\n\n";

    do
    {
        cout << "\n\nGuess the first digit.\n";
        while (!(cin >> a))
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Invalid input. Please try again: \n";
        }

        cout << "\n\nGuess the second digit.\n";
        cout << a;
        while (!(cin >> b))
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Invalid input. Please try again: \n" << a;
        }

        cout << "\n\nGuess the third digit.\n";
        cout << a << b;
        while (!(cin >> c))
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Invalid input. Please try again: \n" << a << b;
        }

        cout << "\n\n====================================================\n\n";

        if (tries == 0)
        {
            cout << "YOU RAN OUT OF GUESSES! \n";
            cout << "The secret number is " << x << y << z << "!\n";
            cout << "PLEASE RESTART THE PROGRAM TO TRY AGAIN!\n";
            correct = true;
        }
        else if ((a == x) && (b == y) && (c == z))
        {
            cout << "YOU GUESSED THE SECRET NUMBER IN " << guess << " TRY / TRIES!\n";
            cout << "CONGRATULATIONS!\n\n";
            correct = true;
        }
        else if ((a == x) && (b == y) && (c != z))
        {
            cout << "You guessed TWO of the numbers correctly!\n";
            cout << "You have " << tries << " tries left.\n";
            correct = false;
        }
        else if ((a == x) && (b != y) && (c != z))
        {
            cout << "You guessed ONE of the numbers correctly!\n";
            cout << "You have " << tries << " tries left.\n";
            correct = false;
        }
        else if ((a == x) && (b != y) && (c == z))
        {
            cout << "You guessed TWO of the numbers correctly!\n";
            cout << "You have " << tries << " tries left.\n";
            correct = false;
        }
        else if ((a != x) && (b == y) && (c == z))
        {
            cout << "You guessed TWO of the numbers correctly!\n";
            cout << "You have " << tries << " tries left.\n";
            correct = false;
        }
        else if ((a != x) && (b == y) && (c != z))
        {
            cout << "You guessed ONE of the numbers correctly!\n";
            cout << "You have " << tries << " tries left.\n";
            correct = false;
        }
        else if ((a != x) && (b != y) && (c == z))
        {
            cout << "You guessed ONE of the numbers correctly!\n";
            cout << "You have " << tries << " tries left.\n";
            correct = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "You guessed NONE of the numbers correctly!\n";
            cout << "You have " << tries << " tries left.\n";
            correct = false;
        }

        cout << "\n====================================================\n\n";
        guess++;
        tries--;
    } while (correct == false);


}
```

I have a little problem though, in this part of the program,

```
cout << "\n\nGuess the first digit.\n";
        while (!(cin >> a))
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Invalid input. Please try again: \n";
        }
```

I could enter anything invalid and it will properly identify it as an invalid input. But if I enter 2 digits (22 for example), the program still enters 22 and it just accepts it.

I don't know exactly how that part of my program works, I just copy-pasted it. Is it possible to modify it, or my program to only accept **a single digit, 0-9**, and identify the input as invalid when two numbers are entered?

I know it's just a minor inconvenience and doesn't really break the program, but if I can make it better then it would be great. I just want it to be perfect, if possible.

I'm guessing if there's something like _getche for integers then it would be better?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `a` should be of type `char`, no? You can test if its a digit using the [`std::isdigit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) function, or write your own. To get the numeric value of the digit character simply use `a - '0'` then.

Comment: why don't you make a check whether it's two-digit number or a single digit number.?

Comment: @y_159 Yes of course I've seen that, that's why I asked why it's not  a single `char`, if the OP wants single digits inputs.

Comment: *I'm a beginner so these will not be efficient* - One of the things you learn as you get more experienced is that there are more important things than efficiency. In fact it's a bit puzzling why beginners rate efficiency so highly.

Comment: I didn't know you could "convert" a char digit to it's numeric value before I read your comment. That would be very handy. Thank you.

Comment: Well, it's just that, as a beginner, I thought that someone with more experience would write the program with less code using an elegant solution. Good to know that efficiency is not the most important. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`while (!(cin >> a))` means keep looping while not able to convert the input to an integer value in `a` - you can add extra conditions:

```
while (!(cin >> a) || a < 0 || a > 9)
```

In those latter cases, there's no need to `.clear()` and `.ignore(...)` but it won't do any harm.

In case it's new to you, `||` means logical-or, the equivalent logic to English such as: *"a is less than 0 OR a is greater than 9"*.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @AgapitoHampaslupa If this post answers your question, please think about accepting it!